# Create a surfaceview on button click in Android

Tags: java, android, game-engine

I am trying to make a simple game in android as practice and for the game I wanted to create a main menu. In my code, the mainmenu.class has a button which when clicked will open a gamepanel.class which has a surface view where I can make my animations. However I am unable to make the button open the surfaceview. Can anyone please show me an example on how to do this? I would really appreciate the help. Thanks :)

Comment: Share your test code.

Comment: Have you tried "setContentView()" method in View.OnClickListener implementation?

Comment: I tried that but it was not working. I fixed though, by making an intent and then running on it. Thanks! :)